# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update an entity but when I do saveChangesAsync() I'm getting this error message:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Before updating, I'm getting this entity like this in my repository class:

```
public IQueryable<Profile> getProfileByUserEmail(string userEmail)
{
    return _context.Profiles
            .Include(pr => pr.Photos)
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(p => p.UserEmail == userEmail);
}
```

In my service, I call my repository class and materialize the query with the `FirstOrDefaulAsync()` like this:

```
public async Task<Profile> getProfileByUserEmail(string userEmail)
    => await _repository.getProfileByUserEmail(userEmail).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

In my controller I get the profile, add a new photo and update it, like this:

```
var profile = await _service.getProfileByUserEmail(userEmail: model.UserEmail);

Photo newPhoto = new Photo();
newPhoto.Description = model.Description;
newPhoto.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
profile.Photos.Add(newPhoto);

var updated = await _service.update(profile);
```

This is my `Profile` entity:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }        
    public HashSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

and my `Photo` entity:

```
public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

I have found on the internet the reason but not a possible solution, if anybody could help that would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `_service.update()` method do? Please show us that code, too!

Comment: Guid PKs by default are auto-generated. Try commenting out/removing `newPhoto.Id = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: @marc_s the service.update calls the repository.update and in the repo.update I just have a public async Task<book> update(Profile profile) {                        
_context.profiles.update(profile); return await _context.saveChangesAsync>0;